# CSS messed up on mobile - bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, media-queries

I am working on a bootstrap website where I have to divide the width screen to 5 equal columns as Bootstrap doesn't provide functionality for 5 equal columns, SO i have created my own, As it works good on desktop, but it messed up on mobile. I have tried my best but unable to figure out what is wrong here.

Here is the code sample.

```
<div class="row" style="margin: 0;">
    <div class="conatiner-fluid services">
        <a href="/applications">
            <div class="col-md-5 apps text-center">
                <img src="images/home-page-tiles/apps.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3> APPLICATIONS</h3>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default home-page-explore hvr-grow-shadow">Explore</button>

                </div>
            </div>
         </a>

        <a href="/social">
            <div class="col-md-5 apps text-center">
                <img src="images/home-page-tiles/social.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3> SOCIAL </h3>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default home-page-explore hvr-grow-shadow">Explore</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>

        <a href="/digital">
            <div class="col-md-5 apps text-center">
                <img src="images/home-page-tiles/digital.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3> DIGITAL </h3>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default home-page-explore hvr-grow-shadow">Explore</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>

        <a href="/web">
            <div class="col-md-5 apps text-center">
                <img src="images/home-page-tiles/web.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3> WEB </h3>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default home-page-explore hvr-grow-shadow">Explore</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>

        <a href="/design">
            <div class="col-md-5 apps text-center">
                <img src="images/home-page-tiles/design.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3> DESIGN </h3>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default home-page-explore hvr-grow-shadow">Explore</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>

    </div>
</div>
```

and the css for this section:

```
.col-xs-5,
.col-sm-5,
.col-md-5,
.col-lg-5 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 269px;
    padding: 0;
}

.col-xs-5 {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .col-sm-5 {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .col-md-5 {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .col-lg-5 {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }
}

.apps {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.caption {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 55%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.caption h3 {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: menuFont;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    margin: 0;
    text-shadow: 2px 3px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    -webkit-text-shadow: 2px 3px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    -moz-text-shadow: 2px 3px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    -o-text-shadow: 2px 3px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
.home-page-explore {
    background-color: transparent;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    color:white;
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin-top:10px;

}
.home-page-explore:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    color:white;

}
```

On Mobile, The headings and buttons shifted to left side and on I-PHONE 6 and up models, headings and buttons doesn't show at all.

here is the [link](http://handlebar.digital/) of the website for those who want to see the issue in real time

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution-
Use all classes on the div(col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 ).

```css
.col-xs-5,
.col-sm-5,
.col-md-5,
.col-lg-5 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 269px;
    padding: 0;
}

.col-xs-5 {
    width: 20% !important;
    float: left;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .col-sm-5 {
        width: 20% !important;
        float: left;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .col-md-5 {
        width: 20% !important;
        float: left;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .col-lg-5 {
        width: 20% !important;
        float: left;
    }
}

.apps {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.caption {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 55%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.caption h3 {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: menuFont;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    margin: 0;
    text-shadow: 2px 3px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    -webkit-text-shadow: 2px 3px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    -moz-text-shadow: 2px 3px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    -o-text-shadow: 2px 3px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
.home-page-explore {
    background-color: transparent;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    color:white;
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin-top:10px;

}
.home-page-explore:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    color:white;

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row" style="margin: 0;">
    <div class="conatiner-fluid services">
        <a href="/applications">
            <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 apps text-center">
                <img src="images/home-page-tiles/apps.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3> APPLICATIONS</h3>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default home-page-explore hvr-grow-shadow">Explore</button >

                </div>
            </div>
         </a>

        <a href="/social">
            <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 apps text-center">
                <img src="images/home-page-tiles/social.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3> SOCIAL </h3>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default home-page-explore hvr-grow-shadow">Explore</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>

        <a href="/digital">
            <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 apps text-center">
                <img src="images/home-page-tiles/digital.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3> DIGITAL </h3>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default home-page-explore hvr-grow-shadow">Explore</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>

        <a href="/web">
            <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 apps text-center">
                <img src="images/home-page-tiles/web.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3> WEB </h3>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default home-page-explore hvr-grow-shadow">Explore</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>

        <a href="/design">
            <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 apps text-center">
                <img src="images/home-page-tiles/design.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3> DESIGN </h3>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default home-page-explore hvr-grow-shadow">Explore</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please see this https://s27.postimg.org/4pcnx6fz7/asdsadsad.png    , text and button are still on left side